# Initializing the elements of a Boost.Fusion sequence from another sequence

Tags: c++, templates, boost-fusion

I've got a Boost.Fusion sequence of elements that need to be initialized one each with the elements of another sequence. When I'd not use Fusion, this would look like:

```
class A {
    A1 a;
    A2 b;
    A3 c;
};

class B {
    B1 a; 
    B2 b;
    B3 c;

    B( const A& o ) : a(o.a), b(o.b), c(o.c) {}
};
```

My only idea to realize this with Fusion vectors is something like

```
BVector b( transform( AVector(), magic_functor() ) );
```

In this idea, `magic_functor` would have a result type of `Bi` for an `Ai` and perform the construction in its `operator()`.
However, `magic_functor` would have to know the right type to cast to, which would result in duplicate logic.

Is there any better way of fusion-ifying the initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace your classes with `fusion::vector`s, like this:

```
typedef boost::fusion::vector<A1, A2, A3> A;
typedef boost::fusion::vector<B1, B2, B3> B;
```

In this case, you can initialize `B` from `A` simply by using [`vector`'s "copy" constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html#fusion.container.vector.expression_semantics) (it is not a real copy constructor since it can accept any forward sequence):

```
A a(A1(...), A2(...), A3(...)); // instance of A
B b(a);                         // each element of b is initialized from the 
                                //corresponding element in a
```

It should be noted that `A` and `B` does not even need to be the same kind of sequence: you can initialize a `fusion::vector` from a `fusion::list`, or a `fusion::set` from a `myCustomForwardSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an uninitialized version of b (special constructor might be needed for that) and then just use copy:

```
BVector b(no_init);
boost::fusion::copy( a, b );
```

Comment: Why default initialize `b` when you can initialize it directly with `a`? `BVector b(a);`

Comment: @LucTouraille That's true as long as BVector be fusion's vector, or maybe some other fusion container. But the question doesn't specify that.

Comment: Quotes from the question: "I've got a Boost.Fusion sequence of elements", "realize this with Fusion vectors", "fusion-ifying the initialization". I think it is pretty clear we are dealing with Fusion sequences :). All sequences provide a constructor to initialize from a forward sequence.